# What are the ways to backup and restore database from higher version of SQL server to Lower version?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016, restore, sql-server-2019

What are the ways to backup and restore database from higher version of SQL server to Lower version?

I have tried generate scripts,import export but nothing works perfectly. Please suggest some other method. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot natively restore a backup to a lower version of SQL Server. Various tools exist that can script data and schemas (including SSMS), however recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use generate scripts for the schema **only**, run that on an empty DB at the lower version, then use the import/export wizard to migrate the data to the new DB.

You may need to edit the generated script that creates the schema a little, removing IDENTITY properties on columns for example.